# Sort Array of object by a porpertie with Mongodb using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to sort a simple array of objects but i am struggling with it. I read several post about how to do it and many of them recomend $unwind the array then $sort and then $group... but it is not working for me because after group i lose the "name" porpertie

Here is my document:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 60.06045071030959
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 52.79790691903873
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 71.76133439165544
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 34.85718117893772
                }
        ]
}
```

I am trying this

```
{ $unwind: '$scores' },
{ $sort: { 'score': 1 } },
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        scores: { $push: '$scores' }
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 71.76133439165544
                },
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 60.06045071030959
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 52.79790691903873
                },
            
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 34.85718117893772
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: add one more accumulator  in the group  like   `name : { "$first" : "$name"}`

Comment: well... i did not read properly the $sort documentation, thank you! is working!

Comment: Hi @Takis_, can you add into answer section so Post Owner can accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok i did so other people don't come trying to answer because its solved question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- your query with small changes and with the `$first` extra accumulator
- all ids will have the same name, because they belonged to the first 1 document before the unwind, so we just take one (the first)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49ef)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": {"path": "$scores"}},
 {"$sort": {"scores.score": -1}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id",
    "name": {"$first": "$name"},
    "scores": {"$push": "$scores"}}}])
```